# Linux rename command but for dynamic values

Tags: linux, rename, filenames

I have files on a Linux server for example:

```
2103acc.001.lob
2507acc.002.lob
2222acc.021.lob
1210acc.051.lob
```

I would like to change them to:

```
2103acc.pdf
2507acc.pdf
2222acc.pdf
1210acc.pdf
```

I cannot performo

```
rename .001.lob .pdf *.lob
```

because those are dynamics number

Can someone write me the solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This regexp should remove digits followed by .lob and replace with .pdf:

```
rename -n -v 's/\.[0-9]+\.lob$/\.pdf/' *.lob
```

Once you're convinced you have the right pattern, just remove the -n (dry-run) and let it run properly:

```
rename  -v 's/\.[0-9]+\.lob$/\.pdf/' *.lob
```

Answer (score 0):

Ixer missed a `*` in his answer, so i added it:

`rename -n -v 's/\.[0-9]*\.lob$/\.pdf/' *.lob`

Comment: I have file 240815acc.001.lob  and after the command executed file is still 240815acc.001.lob

Comment: you need to remove the `-n` because it only shows what files get changed and doesn' execute the command.

Comment: Hi rename  -v 's/\.[0-9]*\.lob$/\.pdf/' *.lob   still is not working

Comment: How can I debug the issue?

Comment: Do you have a similar output like me http://i.imgur.com/xFALLdW.png ? Is there a message that says that a file got renamed?

Comment: @Dejan: If something's not working for you, you need to give more details than "is not working". What happened - did you get an error message? (What error message?). Did any files get renamed to the wrong name? (What name?). Did any files not get renamed? (Which files)? Did smoke start coming out of your computer? Etc... :)

Comment: Hi  I understand that but really nothing happens I do not have any error message but file is not changed

Comment: I tried with rename  .lob .pdf *.lob and it worked but rename  -v 's/\.[0-9]*\.lob$/\.pdf/' *.lob does not work... That is why I am asking if maybe I can debug it somehow?

Comment: @Wachiwi yes I am using exactly the same command as you are but nothing happens. This is really strange. Maybe it has something to do with privileges? I gave the 755 permission to the file

Comment: maybe can I try with mv command in the same folder? Can that be the solution if for some reason it does not work using rename. Is the regular expression similar?

Comment: @Dejan `mv` does not support regex afaik